How can I use regex to replace text with a new line or CR/LF?
I'm using Phoenix Code — the editor based on Brackets — as a text editor, but this is a more general issue with search and replace and new lines in regular expressions.
I will often have several paragraphs of text where I want to remove extra CR/LFs, for example:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. 


Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo.


In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.

The regex search and replace function lets me search for two carriage returns — I just use [\r\n]{2}. Easy peasy. But I can't figure out how to then replace them with a single CR/LF.
If I use \r\n or [\r\n] or any other variations, it simply replaces my search text with those literal characters. I've tried every combo I can think of.
How can I search for a string (any string) and replace it with a carriage return and new line using regex?
Thanks for any help!
PS: Notepad++ has the "extended" search/replace that lets me use '\r\n' in the Replace box, but I don't want to have to switch to it just for those searches if possible. I'd like to be able to do it in regex so I can use it in other editors.

@barmar oh sorry I thought I saw python tag for some reason

Try typing Alt-Return in the replacement box. This is a common way to enter a literal line break.

[\r\n]{2} are not "two carriage returns" in every case. You either want to search for (\r\n){2} or for \n\n. If your software doesn't understand \r or \n as replacement, then it probably won't interpret anything in there as regex-like at all (also not \x0d). What does the documentation/help say?

Hey, @AmigoJack! I thought the same thing — that I needed parens rather than square brackets — but it only worked when I used square brackets. (Regardless, my issue was with the replace box.)
The documentation doesn't say anything about it other than it can do a regex search. The problem isn't just with Phoenix/Brackets, but other text editors that allow regex searches, e.g., Ghostwriter. I was hoping there was a general solution.
I suspect you're right and that "it probably won't interpret anything in there as regex-like at all." Dang.

There is no "general solution" in the world of regex, since every regex library has its own implementation. Even if they follow the same specs, they may be different (one may be older, another may be newer, as is the case with ECMAScript versions).

That would all be poor regex support then. Notepad++ does that perfectly: you search for ([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) and can replace that with \3-\2-\1 to freely arrange what you captured in the groups (parenthesis). Also: if you don't find anything with (\r\n){2} then you don't have Windows linebreaks there - try either \n\n (Unix) or \r\r (Mac).

I can't speak to how to do this in your editor, but here is a general answer to your regex question.
You can limit consecutive line breaks to one with s/[\r\n]{2,}/\n/g. This uses the substitute command on the regex [\r\n]{2,}, which looks for two or more carriage returns (CR) or line feeds (LF), offering a replacement string of \n, one line feed. The g modifier means global: replace all matches.
Here's an interactive demo using Javascript:


function convert() {
  let pre = document.querySelector("pre");
  let button = document.querySelector("button");
  if (pre.old) {
    pre.innerHTML = pre.old;
    delete pre.old;
    button.textContent = "Convert";
  } else {
    pre.old = pre.innerHTML;
    pre.innerHTML = pre.innerHTML.replace(/[\r\n]{2,}/g, "\n");
    button.textContent = "Revert";
  }
}
pre { white-space: pre-wrap }
<button onclick="convert()">Convert</button>
<pre>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. 


Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo.


In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.</pre>



This lets you toggle the conversion (it saves the original content in pre.old, which is saved in the element). It simply sets variables for the <pre> text and the button, reverts if there is saved old content, and otherwise performs the substitution using String.prototype.replace(). The CSS simply ensures the text wraps.

Replace with Regex is not currently supported in Phoenix Code Editor but a feature request has been filed...
https://github.com/orgs/phcode-dev/discussions/1039
